How to Configure and Use My Existing WhatsApp Business Number with Twilio API?
I have successfully created a webhook and configured it to handle incoming messages and send responses using Twilio's API. However, I'm currently using a Twilio-provided WhatsApp Business number. I need to switch to my existing WhatsApp Business number so that when clients message my number, it triggers the webhook and Twilio API sends the response.
1.Created a Twilio account and set up the WhatsApp Sandbox for testing.
2.Verified my WhatsApp Business number with WhatsApp.
3.Configured webhook URLs in the Twilio console to handle incoming messages.
4.Successfully handled incoming messages and sent responses using Twilio's provided number.

You can register your own Whatsapp number using the BYON, follow the tutorial
